# Downloading Azure Devops Artifact from Another Collection

Tags: azure, azure-devops

While creating a pipeline for a project it depends on another project that's located in a different Azure DevOps collection and even though Azure Pipelines lets you download artifacts from the collection the project belongs to, I couldn't find the same solution for the projects outside of the current collection.

Azure structure:

```
- CollectionOne
  - ProjectOne
  - ProjectTwo
- CollectionTwo
  - ProjectThree
  - ProjectFour
```

The `ProjectOne`, depends on the `dll` files produced by the `ProjectFour`.

How can this be done?

edit 1:

This is my `nuget` pipeline item.

[image: azure pipeline item screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ProjectOne is the main project and you want to use ProjectFour as something like a libary.
You could try to run pipelines for the ProjectFour updates then upload the files into the Azure Artifact[image]

Then you could use the Artifacts in other collections by setting corresponding service connection.

Here take nuget package as the uploaded Artifact as an example:
You could use 'nuget' task in pipelines, choose to use feeds in my config.

[image]

You could need to use 'nuget' service connection to communicate with the feeds outside the collection [image]

If you don't have one, you could click add new [image] in the third screenshot to create one for using

[image]

Choose 'External Azure DevOps Server' here and fill the following blanks.

[image]

Then you are supposed to be able use the nuget files in the other collection's artifact.

Comment: I couldn't locate the fourth screenshot, on which page should I be seeing it?

Comment: Hi oividiosCaeremos, you could click the add icon to create a new service connection, have update the steps a little bit.

Comment: I added my `nuget` pipeline item. It doesn't have a `External Azure Devops Server` option.

Comment: Oh, I selected the `Feeds I select here` and that why I couldn't see the option. Now it works like a charm. Thank your <3

Comment: I am so glad that could do some help. Happy coding!